# Rust FFI and Aliasing: C -> Rust -> C -> Rust call stacks with C values being aliased: Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, ffi

I'm trying to wrap my head around Rust's aliasing rules in the following situation:

Let's assume we have a memory allocation in C. We pass a pointer to this allocation to Rust. The Rust function does something with the allocation, and then calls back to C code (*without any parameters*), where another rust function is called with the same allocation as parameter. For now, let's assume that only the first Rust function gets a mutable reference.

The call stack would look like:

```
Some C Code (owns data)
  Rust(pointer as &mut)
    Some C code (does not get parameters from Rust)
      Rust(pointer as &)
```

As a short example, let's assume the following two files:
test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void first_rust_function(int * ints);
void another_rust_function(const int * ints);
int * arr;
void called_from_rust() {
        another_rust_function(arr);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        arr = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        arr[0]=3;
        arr[1]=4;
        arr[2]=53;
        first_rust_function(arr);
        free(arr);
}
```

test.rs

```
use std::os::raw::c_int;
extern "C" { fn called_from_rust(); }
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn first_rust_function(ints : &mut [c_int;3]) {
    ints[1] = 7;
    unsafe { called_from_rust() };
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn another_rust_function(ints : &[c_int;3]) {
    println!("Second value: {}", ints[1])
}
```

(For the sake of completeness: running this code prints "Second value: 7")

Please note that the call back to C from Rust (`called_from_rust()`) does not have any parameters. The Rust compiler therefore does not have the information that anyone might read from the pointed-to value.

My gut feeling tells me that this is undefined behaviour, but I'm not certain.

I've had a quick look at Stacked Borrows, and that model is violated. In the above example only the `Rule (protector)` gets broken, but if `first_rust_function(ints : &mut [c_int;3])` would still use `ints` after calling `called_from_rust()` also additional rules would be violated.

However, I haven't found any official documentation stating that Stacked Borrows are the aliasing model used by the Rust compiler, and that everything considered undefined under Stacked Borrows is actually undefined in Rust. Naively this looks similar enough to coercion of `&mut` to `&`, so it might actually be sane, but given that `called_from_rust()` does not take the reference as parameter, I don't think this reasoning applies.

This brings me to the actual questions:

- Is the above code invoking undefined behaviour (and why/why not?)
- If it is undefined: Would the behaviour be well-defined if `called_from_rust()` would have the pointer as parameter and pass it forward: `void called_from_rust(const int * i) { another_rust_function(i); }`?
- What if both Rust functions were using `&mut [c_int;3]`?

Comment: C bindings should include `restrict` for any mutable reference argument of a bound rust function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the above code invoking undefined behaviour?

Yes, you've broken Rust's pointer aliasing rules. Relying on the Stacked Borrows rules is a bit dubious since, as you've hinted, I don't think it has been officially adopted as Rust's memory access model (even if it was just a formalization on the current semantics). However, something that *is* a practical and concrete ruling is LLVM's `noalias` attribute, which the Rust compiler uses on `&mut` arguments.

> [`noalias`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#noalias)
>
> This indicates that memory locations accessed via pointer values based on the argument or return value are not also accessed, during the execution of the function, via pointer values not based on the argument or return value. ...

So since you access `ints[1]` in `another_rust_function` from a pointer that is *not* based based on the `ints` in `first_rust_function` during the execution of that function, it is a violation. In light of this undefined behavior, I believe the compiler is well within its rights to make the code print "Second value: 4".

---

> Would the behaviour be well-defined if `called_from_rust()` would have the pointer as parameter and pass it forward: `void called_from_rust(const int * i) { another_rust_function(i); }`?

Yes, that will make it well defined. You can see that because the Rust borrow checker can then see that the value can be used in `called_from_rust()` and will prevent improper use of `ints` around that call.

---

> What if both Rust functions were using `&mut [c_int;3]`?

If you used the fix above, where the second borrow is based on the first, then there's no problem. If you didn't though, then it is way worse.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not certain if I had understood everything correctly, but this confirmation puts my mind at ease.

Comment: `noalias` is _less_ standardized than Stacked Borrows. `noalias` is an implementation detail, while Stacked Borrows, while not formerly standardized yet, is agreed upon.

Comment: *"noalias is an implementation detail"* - sure, but it *is* used, it is [documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) that it is used, and in lieu of Rust formalizing anything it can serve as a practical guide for what is and isn't undefined behavior for pointer aliasing.

Comment: Stacked Borrows is more strict than `noalias`, so, while breaking `noalias` is UB, I would argue that breaking Stacked Borrows is, too (and Miri follows this model).